# Convert ASCII Char Array to Hex Char Array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to convert an ASCII character string to a character string in Hexadecimal format like this:

This is the char array: "0123456789ABCDEF" //Len = 16

This should be the output char: "0x30, 0x31, 0x32 ..."

I'm trying this:

```
unsigned char* ascii_char;
unsigned char output_char[16];

ascii_char = "0123456789ABCDEF";

int i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{    
    sprintf(output_char + i * 2, "%02X", ascii_char[i]);
}
```

But the desired response is not as expected. Because if I create a variable like this:

```
unsigned char output_char[16] = {0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46};
```

Works fine the proyect.

Comment: C or C++, choice only one language.

Comment: This is really unclear, what is your problem ?

Comment: @Stargateur I'm looking for the response that the "for" is equal to express the variable like: unsigned char output_char[16] = {0x30, 0x31, 0x32 ...}

Comment: "But the desired response is not as expected." What is the difference between "expected" and "desired"?

Comment: "Because if I create a variable like this: ... Works fine the proyect." So if you do like that, then .... it is good? "I'm looking for the response that the "for" is equal to express the variable like: unsigned char ..." Sorry no idea what you mean. Please make a [mcve], with desired/expected output and actual output. The context it provides might help me understand your question.

Comment: As mentioned by [@xing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575429/convert-ascii-char-array-to-hex-char-array#comment76139949_44575429), you have undefined behavior due to writing out of array bounds. Also, you need to include space for the null-terminator when using `sprintf()`. Why be stingy with the allocation of `output_char[]`?

Comment: "Works fine the proyect." - So why post a question here?? And what is the question?

Comment: sprintf(output_char + i * 2, "%02X", ascii_char[i]); cause gcc run time error : *** stack smashing detected ***: ./test terminated
Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unsigned char output_char[16] = {0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46};`

is exactly the same as

`unsigned char output_char[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";`

give or take maybe a cast from signed to unsigned char, and a trailing zero byte which you can safely ignore.

There is no need to write a loop, to invoke printf(), and to convert anything.

Comment: Maybe a loop and a printf is needed to get what OP describes as 'This should be the output char: "0x30, 0x31, 0x32 ..."'

Comment: The OP says that his project works fine if he declares one thing, and then he tries to build another.  We have no reason to believe that the OP knows what it is that he is trying to do.  I would trust what works, not what the OP thinks should work.

Comment: If you do not trust the code OP provides (for good reasons, I admit), you should try to match the goal described by OP, i.e. the desired output.

Comment: @Yunnosch I disagree.  If the OP is on the wrong path, I am obliged to show him where he is going wrong, not help him go further down the wrong path.

Comment: Ok, lets disagree. No sarcasm, I accept that your interpretation is also valid.

Comment: BTW, if you write `unsigned char output_char[16] = "0123456789ABCDEF"`, then it is even exactly equivalent to the `{ 0x30, ... }`-thing; C omits the terminating `'\0'` in this case.

Comment: @StephanLechner yes, I included a "give or take" part in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is taking an array of characters, which are already stored as hex, and translating it to the *textual representation* of hex codes.

At the end of your loop, `output_char` looks like this:

```
"30313233343536373839414243444546"
```

Or at least it would if the array was large enough to hold it, but it's only half the required size.  You invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by writing past the end of the array.

However, `ascii_char` is *already* in the format you need for `output_char`.  There is no need to do any conversion.